# Trouble with DNS records

Tags: domain-name-system

I have A record for *.example.com that I want to point at my windows server and I want www.example.com and example.com point to my WP server.

I have created the following records:

- A Record - example.com  -  192.0.2.8
- A Record - *.example.com  -  192.0.2.1
- A Record - www.example.com  -  192.0.2.8

When I visit www.example.com I correctly been directed to WP server but when I visit domain.com I visit the window server.

Does the order matters? Do I have to use CNAME from example.com?

Comment: As far as I know with most DNS servers a wildcard record only matches when no explicit record exists, so the above should work, but keep in mind that DNS changes take time to propagate and cached records need time to expire.

Comment: Yes, I have to remember that. I got anxious because www.example.com worked right away. I will wait one day and try again.

Comment: Confirm the actual responses your name servers give with for instance `dig` or `nslookup` - oh, and all bets are off when example.com is also the name of your Windows domain... :D

Comment: I don't fully understand. You're talking about example.com (with the records you mention) and a different domain.com (for which you don't mention how you set up your records). What does domain.com look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows try flushing your DNS

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't change anything. I keep getting the wrong server

Answer (score 0):

Create an A record: www.example.com - 192.0.2.8, then create a CNAME record: example.com - www.example.com

Comment: You can't have both A record and CNAME record for the same domain.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, I actually meant the other way around ... fixed now